# wxPython HtmlWindow not rendering HTML very good

Tags: python, html, wxpython, wxhtmlwindow

I have problems rendering HTML in wxPython's HtmlWindow. It looks like, it **doesn't load .css or image files**!. But maybe there is a way to fix it? I know of `WebView` but it is not available on Linux yet.

**EDIT**

There is a way to do that using wxPython and PyGTK: http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxGTKWebKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, everyone. I found a way to render HTML on Linux. Who is interested take a look here:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxGTKWebKit

Answer (score 1):

Please see: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html.HtmlWindow.html

> If you want complete HTML/CSS support as well as a Javascript engine, see instead [`WebView`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html#html2-webview). [`HtmlWindow`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html.HtmlWindow.html#html-htmlwindow) uses the [`Image`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Image.html#image) class for displaying images, as such you need to initialize the handlers for any image formats you use before loading a page. See [`InitAllImageHandlers`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/functions.html#InitAllImageHandlers) and [`Image.AddHandler`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Image.html#Image.AddHandler) .

So, as the web page said, use [`WebView`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html#html2-webview) instead of `HtmlWindow`.

Comment: I know about `WebView`, but for some reason I can't use it on **Linux**. So thats why I was asking about `HtmlWindow`.

Comment: Then I've no idea about the CSS, but you can use images on it using the `InitAllImageHandlers` and `Image.AddHandler` methods.